# I am able to list a directory and all subdirectories now I want to search in that data structure for specific words and replace them

Tags: python

Every month I have to make what we call a patch build at work. All it is, is a specific file structure of folders and subfolders with the current months Microsoft updates in there, along with a script to run it all from an excel file for our servers.
I am just trying to automate the file structure part of it by making a small program that will make a new directory copied from the previous month. Then change all folders with the previous months name in it to the current month. below is what I have so far it works great. Now I just need to isolate parts of the folder names and change them throughout the entire directories structure.

My question is how do I search through a folder and all sub folders and change just one part of the folder names. In this case any folders the May in it need to be changed to June

```
import os, fnmatch
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

src_path = "C:\CND_Patch_Builds\May 2021 Patches"  #path to copy
dst_path = "C:\CND_Patch_Builds\June 2021 Patches" #path to create and or list the directories and subdirectories of
os.chdir(src_path) #changes from root directory to working directory src_path
print(os.getcwd())

def listdirs(dst_path):  #function that list a directory and all its subdirectories 
    for folder in Path(dst_path).iterdir():
        if folder.is_dir():
            print(folder)
            listdirs(folder)


if not os.path.isdir(dst_path):  #if statement that copies the src_path and makes a new one under the dst_path if dst_path doesn't already exist
    copy_patch = shutil.copytree(src_path, dst_path)
    shutil.move(copy_patch, dst_path)
    print(f"{dst_path} has been created")
    print("Directory and Subdirectories listed below\n")
    listdirs(dst_path)



else:
    print(f"{dst_path} exists\n")  #uses the listdirs function if dst_path already exists
    listdirs(dst_path
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your question so it makes sense. You don't seem to have an actual question; what is it? BTW have you looked at `os.walk` which does this folder walking non-recursively, and you don't have to code+debug yourself? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk

Comment: To clarify I just want to know if it’s possible to search through an entire directory and change one per of all of its sub folder names.